# 過去に生成した日付付きファイル名をスクリプトにて選択したい

Tags: linux, shellscript

現在、dateコマンドを使用して付与したファイルがあります。
■例：20180101.zip　～　20180131.zip

選択した日付の9時から次の日の9時までの中で
zipを解凍せず、中身から特定の文字列に該当している行が
何行あるのかを調べるスクリプトを作成しましたがうまく動作しません。
ご教授頂けますでしょうか。

- スクリプトで連続する整数を表示したい際、1～31ではなく、01～31を表わせる方法があれば教えて頂きたいです。
- 参照する2つのファイルを選択するため、 a a+1 のような差分にて出力ができる構成があればと存じます。

■コマンド例：

```
#!/bin/sh
i=10
j=`$i+1`
while [ $i -ne 20 ];
do
echo "`ls 201801"$i".zip 201801"$j".zip | xargs -n1 -IX unzip -p X | awk -F - '"Dec "$i" 09:00:00" <= $1 && $1 < "Dec "$j" 09:00:00"' | grep ',allow,' | wc -l`"
  i=`expr $i + 1`
  j=`expr $j + 1`
done
```

以上よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 「うまく動作しません。ご教授頂けますでしょうか。」は質問ではなく開発要求です。後半のように質問は具体的に記述してください。

Comment: コードだけではなく質問内容も当初より大きく変わっているようですが、（最初の質問内容を前提とした）回答が付いた状態なので、出来れば情報を整理して別質問で仕切り直した方が良さそうです。

Comment: 確かにそうですね。
失礼致しました。
別途、質問にて仕切り直させていただきます。

Answer (score 1):

> スクリプトで連続する整数を表示したい際、1～31ではなく、01～31を表わせる方法があれば教えて頂きたいです。

`seq`コマンドで連続する数を生成できます。手元のバージョンは`-f`でフォーマット指定できました。

```
$ seq -f "%02.f" 1 10
01
02
03
04
05
06
07
08
09
10
```

ファイル名が日付ならそのまま渡してしまってもいいかも。

```
$ seq 20180110 20180120
20180110
20180111
20180112
20180113
20180114
20180115
20180116
20180117
20180118
20180120
```

> 参照する2つのファイルを選択するため、 a a+1 のような差分にて出力ができる構成があればと存じます。

`expr`コマンドを使うと文字列で表現した式を計算できます。

```
$ expr "1 + 1"
2
```

`for`、`seq`、`expr`を組み合わせて

```
$ for i in `seq 20180110 20180120`; do echo $i `expr $i + 1`; done
20180110 20180111
20180111 20180112
20180112 20180113
20180113 20180114
20180114 20180115
20180115 20180116
20180116 20180117
20180117 20180118
20180118 20180119
20180119 20180120
20180120 20180121
```

Comment: ＞sayuriさん
ご回答ありがとうございます。
現状、2つのファイルを参照し、9時～9時の範囲にて
対象の文字列が含まる行数を1日～31日分を一括で出力したいと
考えております。
参照する2つのファイルを選択するため、
a
a+1
のような差分にて出力ができる構成があればと存じます。
seqコマンドにて「+1」出来る記述方法があれば教えていただけないでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

> 選択した日付の9時から次の日の9時までの中でzipを解凍せず、中身から特定の文字列に該当している行が何行あるのか

日付を選択するのではなく、日付ごと(月初〜月末)に集計する場合を考えてみました。

```awk
unzip -p '201801*.zip' |
awk -F'[ :]' '
    $2>1 && $3<9 && $0~",allow,"{ cnt[$2-1]++ }
    $3>=9 && $0~",allow,"{ cnt[$2+0]++ }
  END{
    for (d in cnt) {
      printf("201801%02d: %d\n", d, cnt[d])
    }
  }
'
```

unzip コマンドの引数をシングルクォートで囲んでいる(`'201801*.zip'`)のは、ワイルドカード(`*`)をシェルに展開させないためです(unzip 内で展開されます)。
awk スクリプトでは午前0時から午前9時までの該当数を前日分として集計しています(`cnt[$2-1]++`)。`$2>1` としているのは1月1日(月初)の午前0時から午前9時までをスキップするためです(質問文に掲載されているコードでは "Dec" となっていますね…)。